# preg_replace PHP between some quotes

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I am a bit confused by preg_replace as I have not used regex before.
I did a bit of searching and couldn't find anything that worked for my situation.

I have logs that contain connections made to the server, like this:

```
Username connected, address "123.123.123.123:1234"
```

I want preg_replace to look for this part:

```
address "123.123.123.123:1234"
```

And change it to this:

```
address "snip"
```

Basically snipping the IP address out, so these logs can be published publicly on the website.

Here's what I currently have that I was testing with.

```
$new_log = preg_replace('/\address\s"(.*)"/', '', $old_log);
```

I just need help getting the regex correct.

Comment: Please show your current code which you have!

Comment: My bad! Here's what I currently have that I was testing with. I think it may be a complete failure, this is my first time attempting to use regex ever. (no idea how to use those code tags, this is my first time using stackoverflow ;_;)


   $new_log = preg_replace('/\address\s"(.*)"/', '', $old_log);

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using a regular expression to validate an email address](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/201323/using-a-regular-expression-to-validate-an-email-address)

Comment: This two issues with your regex are: `.*` needs to be made less greedy with an `?`. And the `\a` escaping doesn't belong there. You probably should constrain it somewhat further with `/address\s+"[\d.:]+"/` where `[\d.:]+` matches any combination of numbers, dots, colon.

Comment: Wow everyone is super useful here! Someone fixed my original post as well. Thank you all so much :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work for you:

(Here I get all lines of the file into an array with [`file()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file.php). After this I replace the part `address "[ip]"` with `address "snip"` with [`preg_replace()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php). At the end I just save the array again in the file with [`file_put_contents()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php))

```
<?php

    $lines = file("logs.txt");
    $lines = preg_replace("/\baddress\s?\".*?\"/", "address \"snip\"", $lines);
    file_put_contents("logs.txt", $lines);

?>
```

regex explanation:

```
\baddress\s?\".*?\"
```

- **\b** assert position at a word boundary (^\w|\w$|\W\w|\w\W)

  - address matches the characters address literally (case sensitive)
- **\s?** match any white space character [\r\n\t\f ]

  - Quantifier: **?** Between zero and one time, as many times as possible, giving back as needed [greedy]
- **\"** matches the character " literally
- **.*?** matches any character (except newline)

  - Quantifier: ***?** Between zero and unlimited times, as few times as possible, expanding as needed [lazy]
- **\"** matches the character " literally

example file before:

```
Username connected, address "123.123.123.123:1234"
Username connected, address "123.123.123.123:1234"
```

after:

```
Username connected, address "snip"
Username connected, address "snip"
```

**Side notes:**

Also a few useful links if you want to read more about regex stuff:

- [test your regex](https://regex101.com/)
- [regex cheat sheet](http://www.cheatography.com/davechild/cheat-sheets/regular-expressions/)
- [PCRE patterns](http://php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.syntax.php)

Comment: Yes! This works perfectly. Do you possible know of any good tutorials to learn regular expression a bit better?

Comment: `array_map` is useless since `preg_replace` can take an array as subject parameter (and obviously returns an array in this case). Why do you use a capture group? There's nothing to capture. Are you sure the second word boundary is needed? Think to the `\K` feature and prefer a greedy negated character class: `[^"]*` to a lazy `.*?`.

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte Thanks, completely forgot that `preg_replace()` also can take an array. (Don't ask about the second word boundary, don't know what I thought there)

Comment: I want to use the page to close another but cannot recommend the lazy quantifier.